# Mensagens de Validação em Inglês no IIS - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Publiquei minha aplicação no IIS, porém, as mensagens de validação está aparecendo em inglês.

Já instalei o pacote do Asp.Net MVC em português na aplicação link:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br/ e configurei o globalization:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe se você possui o referido Idioma (Português do Brasil) instalado no seu servidor, caso não possui apenas siga o seguinte tutorial: http://pt.community.dell.com/support-forums/servidores_e_storage/f/97/t/30456

Qualquer dúvida estamos aqui!